# Python matching partial strings in list elements between two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

In my code I am trying to match the item from 'match' to the the strings in the 'data' list.

I want the code to look at the first word in 'match' list and if it matches with a string in the data 'list' then that will be added to another list.
A second check I want to do is if the first 2 words in 'match' list match with the strings in data.

Currently my output is giving me only one instance of water12 - whereas both shoud have been picked up.

Please could someone let me know where I might be going wrong?

```
match =['f helo','happy hellp','floral', 'alpha','12133','water12 puppies']
data=['f we are', 'hello there', 'alpha beta','happy today is the case','112133 is it', 'floral is my fave', 'water12 if healthy','water12 puppies are here and exist']

lst=[]
for i in match:
    for j in data:
        if i.split()[0] in j:
            lst.append(j)
            data.remove(j)
            break
        if len(i) > 1:
            k= ' '.join(i.split()[:2])
            if k in j:
                lst.append(j) 
                data.remove(j)
                break
                
    else:
        lst.append(i + ' - not found')

print(lst)
```

Desired output:

```
output= [ 'f we are', 'alpha beta','happy today is the case','112133 is it', 'floral is my fave', 'water12 if healthy','water12 puppies are here and exist']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to remove elements from the list you are iterating in. Instead, you can add a condition to verify if the matched word has already been added to your output list.

It should be something like:

```
lst = []
for i in match:
    has_match = False
    for j in data:
        if i.split()[0] in j:
            has_match = True
            print(i, j)
            if j not in lst:
                lst.append(j)
        if len(i) > 1:
            k = ' '.join(i.split()[:2])
            if k in j:
                has_match = True
                print(i, j)
                if j not in lst:
                    lst.append(j)
    if not has_match:
        lst.append(i + ' - not found')
```

I also removed the `break` keywords, since they may stop your code from finding matches in multiple strings in `data`. Using a boolean should do the work. Let us know if you have further questions.

Comment: thank you SO much! I had no idea you could do this and will be so helpful in the future.

Comment: so in my real code I get ` argument of type 'float' is not iterable` they are both lists so not sure why this is happening?

Comment: hmmm maybe you have a float inside one of your lists?

Comment: sorry yes! I had 'nan' which I removed. thank you again!

Comment: just wondering if its possible to print the match item and string from data list with it? Trying to make a dataframe with match name and output? thanks!

Comment: You can add a `print(i, j)` right after `has_match=True`.

Comment: thanks but how would I send that to a dataframe? as im not able to add 2 items to a list? and make 2 seperate columns from this?

Comment: Actually you can add both items to a list by creating a list of tuples. You can create an empty list  `data = []` and then replace the `print` statement with `data.append((i, j))`. At the end of your code, if you want a `pandas.DataFrame` you can just do `dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['Pattern', 'Matched String']`

Answer (score 0):

Try with a list comprehension:

```
output = [x for x in data if any(True if z in x else False for z in x for y in match)]
```

Comment: thanks but this didn't work - I got `['hello there', 'water12 puppies are here and exist']` as the output which is not correct